# How to extract all tags from within a html tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

I am writing a generic html parser and want to be able to extract all the tags from a given tag. Because its a generic parser, outer tags may contain one or more inner tags, and they could be just any html tag, hence I cant use methods like find. I have also tried using .contents but it returns the result in form of a list, but I just want the tags as they are, so that they can be parsed further as bs4 tags.

E.g.: Given the following html:

```
<tr><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr>
```

I need to extract the following, while ensuring that its still of type bs4 tag

```
<th>a</th><th>b</th>
```

Comment: Why is `contents` being a list not correct? It's always going to be an array because a generic parser must accept multiple children in a node. If you can guarantee it's always one, you can just use `contents[0]`

Comment: Could you give more examples? Some that describe what you need more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using `find_all()` method with no arguments?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

html = """<div><tr><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr></div>"""

page = soup(html,"html.parser")

div = page.find('div')

print('Get all tag occurences')
print(div.find_all())

print('Get only the inside tag, without duplicate')
print(div.find_all()[0])
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Get all tag occurences
[<tr><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr>, <th>a</th>, <th>b</th>]

Get only the inside tag, without duplicate
<tr><th>a</th><th>b</th></tr>
```